# Why do I get this warning message on my facebook login page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying the Facebook login API for the first time on a web app deployed locally.

I init the API with the [snippet in their documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2) and have a button on my HTML page

```
<button type="button" onclick="fbLogin()">
```

Where `fbLogin()` is

```
function fbLogin() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log(response);

        // handle the response
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
        } else {
            // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
            // they are logged into this app or not.
        }
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'}); // TODO: If the user doens't provide the email address prompt it for email. Also, don't ask for friend list when its a simple logout maybe? Specify why it's needed first. If it doesn't provide the friends access, re-prompt the request, explaining him it can have a more social experience if he accepts (can see when its friends win and congratulate with them, (we can also prom him to invite some friends))
}
```

When I try to log in the message
"You are using a display type of 'popup' in a large browser window or tab. For a better user experience, show this dialog with our JavaScript SDK without specifying an explicit display type. The SDK will choose the best display type for each environment. Alternatively, set height and width on your window.open() call to properly size this dialog if you have special requirements precluding you from using the SDK. This message is only visible to developers of your application."
shows up.
[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/brg7g7l8oryrwno/Screenshot%202015-02-07%2017.24.49.png?dl=0)

As you can see though, I am not specifying any specific display type; so I really don't know what to do with this message.

Other Google entries didn't have a solution for this problem.

What action do I need to take in order to remove it?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @proulxs: A lot of time has passed and I really can't remember. If you do, be sure to post it down below, so I can accept yours. Bye

Comment: @proulxs did you ever find a solution, Im having the same problem.

Comment: @tech-know I'm not on the project anymore but we never did find a solution. We decided it really wasn't worth the time to worry about this issue since it was only appearing in the dev environment.

Comment: @tech-know it just started working again after a week so I never bothered. Try updating the version of the Facebook SDK or the browser you're using.

Comment: @doplumi Thanks for the reply. I noticed that the problem for me was OSX's full screen mode. It always opens popup windows in a new tab and that was throwing the FB error. And like proulxs said it only shows up in the dev env anyway.

Comment: Seems like a case of Facebook not caring to update their own API.  It used to not open a popup but now it does - maybe for security reasons, who knows!?  At any rate, you just have to ignore the message because it's only shown to a developer of the app.